# Magento: getPrice() and getFinalPrice() returning the same price?

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on implementing a tracking pixel for a client; this pixel needs the price (after discounts) for each item purchased.

On the success page is where I fire this pixel, i'm looping through the items and getting the price. For some reason, when using a coupon `getFinalPrice($qty, $_product)` returns the same total as `getPrice()`

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue? Is there another way to get the price after discounts?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the client was using Amnasty Coupon Mananger Pro (or something like that), which was hijacking the `getFinalPrice()` method, apparently. What finally worked was `$item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscountAmount()`